# Push only if condition is met

Tags: mongodb

In a aggregate I have a group-clause:

```
  {  $group: {
            _id: { town_id: "$_id.town" },
            houses_data: { $push:

                 { house_id: "$_id.house_id",
                   price: {
                       $divide: ["$sum", "$total"]
                         }
                  }
            }
         }
   }
```

**The output looks like:**

```
 {town_id: 13, houses_data: [
    {house_id: 5, price: 32},
    {house_id: 2, price: 12}
  ]
 }
```

**Now I would like** to limit the output of `houses_data`

only to the entries where `house_id > 3`.

**I want this output:**

```
 {town_id: 13, houses_data: [
    {house_id: 5, price: 32}
  ]
 }
```

I tried to add a condition before pushing to the array:

```
             houses_data: { 
               if: {
                  "$_id.house_id": {$gt: 3}
               },
               then: {
                 $push:
                   { house_id: "$_id.house_id",
                     price: {
                       $divide: ["$sum", "$total"]
                         }
                   }
               }
            }
```

**But it doesn't work!** What do I wrong?  Thanks

Comment: can you post your sample document ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try $match as shown below.

```
{
$match:{_id.house_id :  {$gt: 3}}, 

$group: {
            _id: { town_id: "$_id.town" },
            houses_data: { $push:

                 { house_id: "$_id.house_id",
                   price: {
                       $divide: ["$sum", "$total"]
                         }
                  }
            }
         }
   }
```

HTH,

Sandeepkumar Gupta